# R: Extract non-NA elements from a matrix and return with row/column labels

Tags: matrix, extract, tapply

I have a large matrix as a result of using tapply with an INDEX argument of two rows from a dataframe.  Most of the matrix is empty (NA).

Here is how I used tapply: `latavgs <- tapply(geodata$latitude,geodata[5:6],FUN=mean)` where `latavgs` is my resulting matrix, and `geodata` is the dataframe mentioned above.

Is there a way to extract only the non-NA elements from `latavgs` and return them in such a way that I could have the row and column listed, as well as the value?  Or is there a better way to use tapply than what I've done, if I want to take the means of all values in `geodata` that belong to each unique pair of values from `geodata[5:6]`?  I.e., for each unique pair in `geodata[5:6]` I get one mean.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to solve this without fully look at your data. 
Try this: [Why does tapply take the subset as NA and not exclude them totally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632587/why-does-tapply-take-the-subset-as-na-and-not-exclude-them-totally)